# How to I access the A/B testing features after upgrading to 4.6?

Tags: civimail

When I upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6, I don't see anything about the A/B testing features within CiviMail. How do I access these features?

Answer (score 3):

The A/B testing features come with two menu items. For me, they weren't showing up for some reason, even after rebuilding the menu by visiting `civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1`

I don't understand why this worked, but I did the following:

1. Go to "Admin" > "Customize Data and Screens" > "Navigation Menu"
2. Expand the Mailings item and you should see "New A/B test" and "Manage A/B tests" at the bottom.
3. For each of these two items, take the following steps:

   1. Right click on the menu item and choose "Edit"
   2. Change the `#` character in the URL field to something else like `foo`.
   3. Save. Then edit again, and change back to `#`

Comment: Now that I know I'm not the only one, this should get reported as a bug.  I'll do it later today.

Comment: IIRC, the navigation menu is cached on a per-session basis. Editing the menu like you did might force it to update. Another way to force the navmenu to update might be to logout/login.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a typo in the upgrade script.  I filed a bug and a patch:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5652

This fix should be in Civi 4.6.3.  Sean's fix will work, but the permissions will be slightly off - but will be fixed on upgrade to 4.6.3.  This SQL statement will fix the problem with correct permissions:

```
UPDATE civicrm_navigation SET permission = 'access CiviMail', permission_operator = '' WHERE name = 'New A/B Test' OR name = 'Manage A/B Tests';
```